# Unbinding event from component

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a view which contains several textarea components. The question is how to unbind 'click' event from the textarea that was clicked? Only from the particular one.

```
var StreamView = Backbone.View.extend({

 el: "#stream",

 events: {
 "click textarea" : "addSendCommentButton"
 },

 addSendCommentButton : function(event) {

 this.undelegateEvents();

 }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unbind only a specific event you can use something like this:

```
addSendCommentButton : function(event) {
   this.$el.off('click.delegateEvents' + this.cid, 'textarea');
}
```

Backbone attach the events using the jQuery `on` with a specific namespace `delegateEvents` plus the `cid`.

---

I am afraid that this also unbinds the events from other textareas. This is so because the `off` method needs the same selector that the passed to `on` as the jQuery documentation says:

> To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector
>   argument. The selector string must exactly match the one passed to
>   .on() when the event handler was attached.

---

## Suggestion

You can have a similar behaviour changing a little your code:

```
var StreamView = Backbone.View.extend({

 el: "#stream",

 events: {
 "click textarea.unfinished" : "addSendCommentButton"
 },

 addSendCommentButton : function(event) {

    $(event.target).removeClass("unfinished");

 }

});
```

Use a more specific selector to attach the event and remove that class when the callback is called.

Comment: First ol all thx for the answer. Unfortunatelly it also unbinds events from the other textarea components. Please notice that StreamView contains many textarea components ("#stream" div contains many textareas).

Comment: This works. Thx. Unfortunatelly I cannot to vote up (Voting up requires 15 points of reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var StreamView = Backbone.View.extend({

     el: "#stream",

     events: {
     "click textarea" : "addSendCommentButton"
     },

     addSendCommentButton : function(e) {
        e.target.removeEventListener('click', 'addSendCommentButton');
     }

    });
```

Comment: This does not work, in the scope of `addSendCommentButton` `this` is the Backbone object which does not have a `removeEventListener` method

Comment: That is not working either, the listener attached is not `addSendCommentButton` but the function returned by the underscore method `bind` (see the source code of Backbone)

Answer (score 0):

YD1m answer is correct but I want to share with you another way how to do this.
If you want implement one-time event you can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) jQuery method.

You can do this in two ways:

1. By overriding `delegateEvents` method
2. By attaching event after rendering - `this.$('textarea').one('click', _.bind(this. addSendCommentButton, this))`